# mobx: how to observe changes in nested objects?

Tags: mobx

I have two models: a `MessageModel` that contains message text (observable), and `MessageListModel` that contains a list of these `MessageModel` objects (observable too).

I registered a `mobx.autorun()` on each change to the message list.

However, `autorun` triggers on adding/removing messages from list, but not on changing text of existing messages.

Example:

My `MessageListModel`:

```
import { observable, decorate } from "mobx";
import MessageModel from "./MessageModel";
import * as mobx from "mobx";

class MessageListModel {

  messages = [];

  constructor() {
        mobx.autorun(() => {
          console.log('Autorun triggered!');
          console.log(this.messages.length);
        });
    }

  addMessage(text) {
    this.messages.push(new MessageModel({ messageList: this, text: text }));
  }

  getMessageText(index) {
    return this.messages[index].text;
  }

  setMessageText(index, messageText) {
    this.messages[index].text = messageText;
  }
}

decorate(MessageListModel, {
  messages: observable,  // don't wanna use decorator syntax
})


export default MessageListModel;
```

my `MessageModel`:

```
import { observable, computed, action, decorate } from "mobx";
import {observer} from "mobx-react";

class MessageModel {

  constructor({messageList, text}) {
    this.text = text;
    this.messageList = messageList;
  }

  text = undefined;
}

decorate(MessageModel, {
  text: observable,
})


export default MessageModel;
```

Trying to run this:

```
const messageList = new MessageListModel();

messageList.addMessage('msg1');   // triggers autorun
messageList.addMessage('msg2');   // triggers autorun

messageList.setMessageText(1, 'other text');  // does not trigger autorun
messageList.setMessageText(0, 'other text');  // does not trigger autorun either
```

how do I make it observe changes to my messages, and not to their amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `autorun` method, you are only *listening* for changes in the `length` of the message array so the only thing that is tracked in that `autorun` function is the `length` property of the array.

try changing the `autorun` to this to see the difference:

```js
mobx.autorun(() => {
  console.log('Autorun triggered!');
  console.log(this.messages.length);

  this.messages.map((model)=>{
    console.log(model.text)
  })      
});
```

In the example above we are accessing the `text` property on the `model` so any time you change `text` on any model, `autorun` will execute.

So, `autorun` will only run when properties that are explicitly tracked (accessed inside the function) are changed.